# Install a folder with __init__.py in a python package downloaded as a git submodule

Tags: python, package, setuptools, git-submodules, setup.py

In my python project, there is another python project [s2p](https://github.com/centreborelli/s2p) downloaded as a git submodule. How can I install my project and only the `s2p` folder in s2p project without running `s2p/setup.py` in s2p project.
Eg:

```
myproject
    - setup.py
    - mypackage
        - __init__.py
    - s2p
        - setup.py
        - s2p
            - __init__.py
        - many other files ...
```

As you can see, there are two `setup.py` in `myproject/` folder. One is the `setup.py` of `myproject` and another `setup.py` is in a git-submodule `s2p`.

The `myproject/setup.py` looks like:

```
packages=(find_packages(include=["mypackage.*"]) + find_packages(where="./s2p/s2p")),
```

Explanation: I want it to install `mypackage` and only the folder `s2p` under s2p submodule without using `s2p/setup.py`.

Installation: the following is run

```
~/myproject$ pip install -e .
```

But s2p is still not installed correctly:

```
$ python
>>> import s2p
>>> print(s2p.__file__)
None
```

Note: the `myproject/setup.py` installs all required packages to run s2p.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

- Rename `myproject/s2p` to `myproject/s2p_repo`
- Copy `s2p_repo/s2p/` folder under `myproject`. Thus the directory tree is:

```
myproject
    - setup.py
    - mypackage
        - __init__.py
    - s2p_repo
        - setup.py
    - s2p
        - __init__.py
```

- Change the content of `myproject/setup.py` to:

```
packages=find_packages(include=["mypackage.*", "s2p.*"])
```

- And run `pip install -e .`

The above steps can be automated by customizing `develop` command in `setup.py`.
E.g.:

```
from setuptools.command import develop
class CustomDevelop(develop.develop, object):
    """
    Class needed for "pip install -e ."
    """

    def run(self):
        subprocess.check_call("cp -r s2p_repo/s2p s2p", shell=True)
        super(CustomDevelop, self).run()

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(include=["liveeo.*", "s2p.*"]),
    python_requires="~=3.8",
    cmdclass={"develop": CustomDevelop,},
)
```